# simple example of NOT instruction in x86 asm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

Can someone explain what exactly the NOT instruction in x86 assembler does?

In the programming languages I know, NOT is used to check if a particular status is not true (e.g.: `if (!Isset($var)))`.

But in Assembler, the operator seems to do something else, and I do not understand exactly what the operand is for.

Could someone explain the operation using a simple example?

Comment: which part of the instruction description you don't understand?

Comment: i dont understand everything about this instruction. i use google but i dont understand what this instruction do. does it simple change every 0 to a 1? How about 0xffff? does the not instruction change 0xffff to 0x0000?

Comment: yes, it does change every 0 to 1 and 1 to 0. If the `0xFFFF` was in 16 bit register or 16 memory operand, then result is zero. (`not eax` when `eax = FFFF` would produce `eax = FFFF0000`, the operand size matters, like always). http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/NOT.html ... whenever you are not sure, use debugger to try it out, it's quick way plus you will get practice with debugging.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. i have one last question, is it possible to use the not instruction with strings?

Comment: @DR.Jones The CPU doesn't know what a string is.  You can apply `not` to a register holding the address of the string, it does the same as always.

Comment: @DR.Jones no. There are no strings in assembly. Only bits, grouped in bytes, words, double words, etc... So I have no idea what you are asking. What is "string" in high level language is always just value encoded in bits, so yes, you can certainly `not` such value, although I'm not sure what you expect (the usage of such operations seems to me mostly "not meaningful", unless it's some kind of trivial obfuscation scheme).

Answer (score 12):

[x86 `NOT`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/NOT.html) is a bitwise operation; it just inverts each bit separately, like `xor reg, -1` but without affecting FLAGS.

**`NOT` implements [C's `~` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic), and is totally different from `!` ([logical not](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical)).**

Here's how C compilers implement those operators (gcc8.1 and clang6.0 for the x86-64 System V calling convention, [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int+bitnot(int+a)+%7B+return+~a%3B+%7D%0D%0Aint+logical_not(int+a)+%7B+return+!!a%3B+%7D%0D%0Aint+booleanize(int+a)+%7B+return+!!!!a%3B+%7D%0D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:37.18061674008811,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g81,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-march%3Dskylake',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:32.64490422214522,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang600,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O2+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-march%3Dhaswell+-mno-avx512f+-mno-avx',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+6.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:30.174479037766666,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)).  Both compilers generate identical code, correctly picking the most efficient implementation for modern Intel/AMD CPUs.

```
int bitnot(int a) { return ~a; }

    mov     eax, edi
    not     eax
    ret

int logical_not(int a) { return !a; }

    xor     eax, eax
    test    edi, edi
    sete    al
    ret

int booleanize(int a) { return !!a; }

    xor     eax, eax
    test    edi, edi
    setne   al
    ret
```